# Passing a variable to method and using the method return value in C#

Tags: c#, methods, parameter-passing, field, return-value

I am trying to pass a variable to a method, i.e. `velocity(decent)`, and call that method several times in a while-loop.

It seams to not be working and I don't know what is wrong with this.

I want the decent variable to increase up to 250.

I tested the `velocity(decent)` method outside of the while loop and it worked. Inside the while-loop it just stays `0`, while the `altitude` is decreasing each time it goes though the while loop.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

// Every measuerments are in feet and seconds
// This program is to sim a simple jump with no graphics. Work the numbers out for final implementaion.
namespace Jumper1Test
{
    class Program
    {
        //10 - 20 feet above ground pull both cords to slow down to about 0 ft per second
        private static int alt;           //in feet 30,000 20,000, 15,000 ft *Note keep decent same scale\measurment
        private static float decent = 0;  //speed of jumper 250ft per second cute deploed 15-20ft p[er second want to hit 0 when landing
        private static int cuteDelay = 3; //3 second cute delay after opeing (ruf estimate on average)
        private static bool leftCord;
        private static bool rightCord;
        private static bool cuteDeployed; //if parachute is deployed
        private static bool jumped;       //jump iniciated

        //environtmnet effects
        private enum windDrection { North, South, East, West, NE, NW, SE, SW } //NE NW = North East West respectivly
        private static int windspeed;     //in knots

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Jump Sim 1.0");

            //select the hight for the jump
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Jump Altitued:");
            Console.WriteLine("a for 30000 Ft");
            Console.WriteLine("b for 25000 Ft");
            Console.WriteLine("c for 15000 Ft");
            String alt1 = Console.ReadLine();
            if (alt1.Equals("a"))
            {
                alt = 30000;
            }
            else if (alt1.Equals("b"))
            {
                alt = 25000;
            }
            else
            {
                alt = 15000;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The Hight of the jump is " + alt);

            //jumping
            int countdown = 5;
            while (countdown != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Jumping in " + countdown);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); //wait for 1 secod.
                countdown--;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Jump!");

            while (alt != 0)
            {
                alt = alt - 5000;
                Console.WriteLine("Altitue = " + alt);
                velocity(decent);
                Console.WriteLine("Speed is: " + decent);
            }

            // keep screen from going away when run from VS.NET
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static float velocity(float decent)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) //its takes 8 seconds to reach terminal velocity
            {
                decent = decent + 31.25f; //increease speed of fall
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); //wait for 1 secod.
            }
            return decent;
        }//end of velocity
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any question mark.

Comment: How comes you are "trying to pass a global variable to a method" while global variables *don't exist at all in C#*?

Comment: You are not allocating the return value of the `velocity` method to a variable. The variable you pass into the method cannot be altered from within the method because it is a value type.

Comment: @Kriz: static vars come pretty close.

Comment: @Krizz who told you that "global variables don't exist at all in C#"? Ofcouese it exists. You can declare a static variable and it'll surely work as global variable in C#.

Comment: @Sukanya, well, in fact you don't have static variables either in C# :P What you refer to is static field in class which as Henk noted is close to global variables, but they are not the same thing. But it was just nomenclature side-note. Let's not dwelve on this too much.

Comment: @Krizz Yes we can declare a static class. Inside that class, we can declare "static variables" and we can access their values by declaring public static methods(by get and set). And if that variable functions same as global variable then the requirement is fulfilled. Just changing the naming convention doesn't change the functionality. static variables may have some additional features than global variables, but as per functionality is concerned, it can behave same as global.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want :

```
 //velocity(decent);
 decent = velocity(decent);
```

And that also means that `decent` (descent) does not have to be a global variable. It could become a proper local of Main().
Do try to avoid globals as a first step to writing better software.

Also try

```
//Console.WriteLine("Jumping in " + countdown);
Console.Write("Jumping in {0} \r", countdown);
```

for some dazzling video effects.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem your seeing is that you expect your `decent = decent + 31.25f;` in `velocity` to set the value of your class's field defined as `private static float decent;`.

The problem with this is since your parameter is *also* named `decent` it overrides the meaning of your broader scoped `decent` while in the context of `velocity`. In order to achieve this effect, you could either rename the `decent` parameter to something else or use:

```
this.decent = decent + 31.25f
```

I don't quite understand why `decent` is a field though if you want to pass it to a member method.

**It is better to change the declaration of `velocity` to:**

```
private static void velocity()
```

**and then leave your use as you currently have it.**

Comment: Updated to include further insight.

Answer (score 2):

Floats are passed by value. You need to assign the return value back into decent:

```
decent = velocity(decent);
```

The better option is (that since it is a field) just don't pass it to the method at all.

```
private static void velocity();
```

Just instead refer directly to the field `decent` inside the method `velocity`.

Now inside your method, you're referring to the variable passed in `decent`, not to the field `decent` (both are named the same).